# Is it possible data which was generated with JavaScript in Google Chrome could exist in my Mac'sRAM?

Tags: javascript, forensics, operating-systems, memory

I generated a private key using this website: https://www.stellar.org/account-viewer/#!/

I was supposed to write down the private key but I didn't and I lost it. I have since unplugged the internet from my Mac and kept Google Chrome open (but the tab is closed) and have not used the Mac any further.

Is it possible the private key I generated on that website could still exist in my computer's RAM??

EDIT: I found it!!! To anyone who comes to this post and finds this, I closed the tab and dumped 4-5 hours later and I still found it. The computer was kept on and Google Chrome was not closed. Do not give up hope!

Comment: Seems like you'd have to do a coldboot attack on yourself: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cold_boot_attack Very unlikely that it works, however, if you did use this device more and did not (immediately) shut it down.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Very unlikely. The memory used by that page will have been freed and will almost certainly have been decommitted from the process, which means the OS will have scrubbed it by now.

At best you could try taking a memory dump of the process using Volatility, which can also carve out useful structures and look for sensitive information (probably including certificates and RSA private keys, although I haven't looked into that) but I'd imagine that the data is completely gone by now.

Comment: I have $3000 worth of money in wallet I can no longer access. I'll try anything. Is Volatility compatible with Mac?

Comment: Yes. https://github.com/volatilityfoundation/volatility

But sorry, you're probably screwed on this one. My advice is to not put your earnings into magical internet tokens without considering the potential for data loss.

Comment: Is that not just an analysis tool? I can't see where to actually perform a dump?

Comment: There are a bunch of ways to do it. LLDB can do it, you could use OS X readmem, and there's some more info here: https://superuser.com/questions/85853/how-to-dump-memory-to-a-file-in-gdb-osx-need-to-rescue-my-work

Comment: Okay, I got a .aff4 file, so you're saying I now use Volatility to look at it? Can you recommend a tutorial?

Comment: @AzzyDude The Volatility wiki is a good place to start.

Comment: I actually found it!!! It's taken me days to search through it, but I actually found it, even though I dumped 4 hours after closing the tab.

Comment: @AzzyDude I'm very surprised! Glad you found it though.